# How to fix React16.8 and webpack4 app doesn't load

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack-4

I'm developing a react-app with webpack4. It seems to work fine until I updated react from 16.6 to 16.8. After the update, the app is built and compiled successfully but it doesn´t load in the browser (the is no error message shown).

I'm executing `npm start` in development mode (script `webpack-dev-server --mode development`) with webpack4 configuration sown below.

webpack.config.js

```js
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: './src/index.html',
  filename: './index.html',
});

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {},
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [htmlPlugin],
};
```

index.js

```js
window.React = React;

ReactDOM.render(
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={baseTheme}>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <App/>
            </Provider>
        </MuiThemeProvider>,
    document.getElementById('index')
);
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>besolidary!</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="index"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually, no error message is shown neither in the browser or in the npm terminal.

Comment: If I were you, I'd quickly spin up a fresh project with create-react-app.

Comment: Would [v16.9](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/08/react-v16.9.0.html) work? it has many fixes implemented in the latest version.

Comment: No, it does't work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem was the version of `npm`. For React 16.8 or higher in necessary `npm 6.x` (I was using `npm 3.x`). Thanks for your help!